# Can't pass input value to controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have problem with my code. I can't pass input value to controller. So, I have a selection box. The number we choose in selection box will generate how many form will display. So if I select 3 in selection box, the same form will appear 3 times. And than, when I submit the form to save the data, than var_dump() it in controlled before the data get insert into database, I get array (0){} that means null. Can anyone help me? And how to insert multiple row in the same database at the same time?
Thank You

```
             <label for="sel1">Jumlah permintaan rekrut karyawan : 
               </label>
          <select class="form-control" name="sel1" id="sel1" >
        <option selected>Pilih</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-primary">Primary</button></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" id="btn-submit" style="display: none; margin: auto;" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p align="center">Are you sure you want to request ?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="button-smt" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo site_url('hire/submit_hire'); ?>'">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#sel1').on('change', function(event) {
       initForms($(this).val());
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){
        $('.form-horizontal').each(function(){
           $(this).show();
           $('#btn-submit').show();

        });

    });
});
$('#button-smt').click(function(e){  
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('test');
   alert($('#empreqstat').val());
   /* $.ajax function will go here to save row */
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('hire/submit_hire');?>",
        data: {empreqstat : $('#empreqstat').val(), position : $('#position').val(),empstat : $('#empstat').val(), Education : $('#Education').val() , Experience: $('#Experience').val(),jobdesc : $('#jobdesc').val() },
          dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
        error:function(){
            alert('data gagal disimpan');
          }
      });
});

function initForms(formCount){
    var finalHTML= "";
    for(i=0; i<formCount; i++){
        var tempHTML ='<div class="card"><form id="$formid$" action="<?php echo base_url('hire/submit_hire');?>" method="POST" class="form-horizontal striped-rows b-form" style="display:none;"><div class="card-body"><h4 class="card-title">Rekrut Karyawan'+(i+1)+' </h4><div class="form-group row"><div class="col-sm-3"><label class="control-label col-form-label">Employee Request Status</label></div><div class="col-sm-9"><select class="form-control" name="empreqstat" id="empreqstat" ><option selected>Pilih</option><option value="Replacement">Replacement</option><option value="Add">Add</option></select></div></div></div></form></div>';
         tempHTML = tempHTML.split("$formid$").join("form-" + i);
        finalHTML += tempHTML;
    }

    $('.form-container').empty().html(finalHTML);
}
```

My controller:

```
      public function submit_hire(){
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('empreqstat', 'empreqstat', 'required');
      var_dump($_POST);exit;
      }
```

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter why `$_POST` why not `$this->input->post()`?

Comment: I'm using it just to var_dump the value, and I've tried $this->input->post() but not work

Answer (score 0):

This `$('empreqstat').val()` isn't a valid selector.

If I suppose if you `console.log` your data before sending it you would have noticied these variables not being populated. You could also look in dev tools under "headers" for the request to see what data has been posted.

You need something along the lines of `$('name=["empreqstat"]')`

However, the problem with this approach is that you have multiple forms with the same input field names.

So now you have to be even more descriptive.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
    console.log($("input[name='somename']",form).val());
});
```

Comment: is it need to define input per form one by one?

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand. this solution should work for every dynamic form. you are already defining / getting the input values.. just not correctly.